# Face having a weird shape when connecting vertices

Tags: vertices, faces

It looks like the vertices try to draw a line to the center and create the face around that line instead of actually filling the inside of the vertices. What can cause this behaviour and how can I fix it?

**Before trying to create the face:**
[image: before face creation]

**After creating the face:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first screenshot you can see that seemingly all vertices are selected, but usually an edge between two selected vertices should show orange as being selected, too. All your edges are black. So it looks like you have duplicate geometry there.

This is how it looks like in your screenshot:

[image: unconnected vertices]

You have selected unconnected vertices lying on top of the vertices which are connected by the edges. Since all vertices you try to fill are unconnected, Blender has a hard time to figure out in which order the vertices should be connected to form a face. When I hit <kbd>F</kbd> now, I get the same result as you. If all vertices that are connected by edges would be selected, all those edges would be shown as selected too and also be orange like in this screenshot:

[image: connected vertices selected]

To fix this, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices (and immediately the edges should turn orange as well), then hit <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*. This should get rid of the duplicated vertices. If you press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the shape, the result should look like this:

[image: filled shape]

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer!